# NordVpn apt error 'NOSPLIT'

Tags: apt, vpn

i'm trying to install nordvpn on Ubuntu 20.04, but i get ***'NOSPLIT'***.
I tried multiple solutions here in the stack but it seems I can't get an answer.
here what I get after the apt update.

```
    Get:1 http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease [317 B]    
Err:1 http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease            
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
E: Failed to fetch http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/dists/stable/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

after

```
sudo dpkg -i nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
```

seems it didn't add nord repo to sources.list so i add them manually to
/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
deb [arch=i386 ] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
```

and I tried to use different network wifi and provider but no light :(.
thanks for any help.
.

Comment: if i follow that post and add nameserver 8.8.8.8 GPG error:'NODATA" instead of nosplit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found simple solution, you just need to remove nordvpn-release to get PUBKEY,if you run

```
sudo dpkg -i nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb
```

remove it by

```
sudo apt remove nordvpn-release
```

then add

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
```

to your sources.list
and run

```
sudo apt update
```

you will get NO_PUBKEY error

```
W:key is not` available: NO_PUBKEY 6B219E535C964CA1
```

you need key which is last 8 digit from **PUBKEY 5C964CA1** then install it by

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 5C964CA1
```

and finally run

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install nordvpn
```

Comment: I know it's more than 3 years old. But someone like me might want to use Ubuntu 20.04 with Nordvpn so what I did was:
`echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list`

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 5C964CA1`
`sudo apt update`
`sudo apt install nordvpn -y`
`sudo usermod -aG nordvpn $USER`